# View is not rotating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am making a navigation based app and I need only portrait orientation except in a `ZoomPictureViewController` ( Zoom in, zoom out images) that supports all orientations.

I am presenting `ZoomPictureViewController` and returning `YE`S in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

But I get no rotation. I know that **`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`**, **`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`**, **`RotateToInterfaceOrientation`** are only get called on the current/visible view controller but this is not happening in my case. I have checked it via putting breakpoints and `NSLog`.

Comment: Remove the comment for `return YES;` and test it.

Comment: Did you change the supported orientations at the info.plist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9788125/204826

Comment: can you show the code that alloc and init this controller?

Comment: @AlexSalom: I have changed that but no use

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any type of Navigation Controller or a Tab View Controller? I've noticed that there are issues when rotating a UIView that's not the first or only view as a direct child of the main window.

So if your UIView is part of a Navigation Controller or a Tab View Controller, you'll also need to override `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` on the Navigation Controller or Tab View Controller.

Also I here's an important gotcha in the Apple documentation that might explain the problem you are having.

> Tab bar controllers support a portrait
>   orientation by default and do not
>   rotate to a landscape orientation
>   unless all of the root view
>   controllers support such an
>   orientation. When a device orientation
>   change occurs, the tab bar controller
>   queries its array of view controllers.
>   **If any one of them does not support
>   the orientation, the tab bar
>   controller does not change its
>   orientation.**

Comment: I am using Navigation Controller and no viewController supports orientation. only ZoomPictureViewController supports.